# where does magento set frontend cookie in response headers for first time request?

Tags: magento-1.9, cookie

Please tell the location or file where magento set the value of key 'set-cookie' as 'frontend= hashcode' when you hit the request for the first time.

Answer (score 3):

Take a closer look at

- [`Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::preDispatch()`](https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9.2.1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php#L493) and
- [`Mage_Core_Model_Cookie::set()`](https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9.2.1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cookie.php#L238).

Comment: Hi I have included core php setcookie() function,also called in Mage_Core_Model_Cookie::set() and it is not setting the key 'Set-Cookie' in response header on a particular server environment and on other it is working fine.